# Simplify ruby code evaluating the same expression twice

Tags: ruby, optimization

I had this simple scenario many times and I'm not sure how to do it in a ruby concise way:

```rb
  def sign(number)
    if (number <=> 0).zero?
      1
    else
      number <=> 0
    end
  end
```

How can I avoid the `number <=> 0` twice and use some sort of condition or a proper ruby / rails helper?

Edit: I'm trying to find something like this:

```rb
  def sign(number)
    (number <=> 0).is(&:zero?) { |result| 0 }
  end
```

Comment: What are you trying to sort?

Comment: I'm using `<=>` to determine the sign of a number.

But I think what it tries to sort here is beside the point. The question is "How to return a certain value if some "expression"'s return would be X.

Comment: `(number <=> 0).tap { |z| break 1 if z.zero? }`

Comment: `number >= 0 ? 1 : -1`

Comment: So, you want to get -1 if number less than 0 and 1 if number >=0? If so, @alexey comment is the easiest way to implement it

Comment: Yes, said like that.... Thanks I got it now

Comment: The easiest way to avoid duplication is to assign it to a variable.:

Comment: `(val = number <=> 0).zero? ? 1: val`

Comment: @maxpleaner this is what I was looking for.

Comment: `(number <=> 0).nonzero? || 1` would work as well.

Comment: Code should be optimized for reading, not writing and certainly not try to be cryptic. Personally I would pick @AlekseiMatiushkin answer over anything smart or more concise. It is readable!

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest a math approach:

`res = number.abs/number rescue 1`

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Numeric.html#method-i-abs

`rescue 1` just in case of `ZeroDivisionError`